# How do I move my gui window to the same monitor as my console window?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyqt4, multiple-monitors

I want my PyQt gui to open on the same monitor as my console window, but I'm not sure how to detect the location of the console window. I currently use PyQt4 QDesktopWidget to place my window on a desired monitor. Any help is appreaciated.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

## move app to second monitor if available ##
if QDesktopWidget().screenCount() >= 2:
    dwgScreen2 = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(1)
    self.move(dwgScreen2.right() - 350, dwgScreen2.top() + 50)
else:
    self.move(10, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the native console HWND with [`GetConsoleWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx). `MonitorFromWindow` will give you the HMONITOR the window is on and `GetMonitorInfo` will give you the rectangle of this monitor.

Windows does not give you a mapping of HMONITOR to "monitor number" but you probably don't need it in your case.